# Can the curvature of space be measured using a swimming pool?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravity, curvature, estimation

I read somewhere that if the center of mass of two twelve ton elephants was one meter apart then the space they curve would be one nanometer longer. (Though I doubt elephants come that dense)

This got me thinking though. Could an olympic swimming pool which contains about 2500 tons of water be used to observe and measure the curvature of space? (It could be filled with mercury if a higher density is needed)

Would the full swimming pool be about 100 nanometers longer than the empty swimming pool?

Has anyone tried an experiment along these lines?

(On hindsight and from answers to other questions I think the two elephants may be referring to neutron star material or even black holes, as the increased diameter caused by curvature from 12 tons at Earth densities is 20 or 30 orders of magnitude smaller than a nanometer.)

Comment: It might stretch at least that much elastically from the resulting outward force on the pool walls...

Comment: Can you say something more about the meaning of your first sentence? Did you read that the components of the curvature tensor are of the order of $10^{-9}{\rm m^{-1}}$ (which sounds way too high to me)? Maybe draw a diagram for your first sentence, or cite the original source.

Comment: @JonCuster Actually, that quantity going to be rather more than a nanometer. The walls will have Young's modulusses / Bulk modulusses of the order of $10^{10}{\rm Pa}$. The water / mercury pushes on them with a pressure of the order of $10^5{\rm Pa}$, meaning a local strain of the order of $10^{-4}$. So a container with meter thick walls is still going to expand of the order of tens of microns.

Comment: I was being a little low key... Thanks for running the real numbers - real pools do not have meter thick walls which just makes it worse...

Comment: I thought that point may come up;-) We could just lower two lead blocks with holes in the sides into the swimming pool and put a rod through them to measure it.

Comment: Ok. I might remove this question and start again.

Comment: The idea has been exploited with large cryogenic resonators that are acting as gravitational wave antennas. There is no need to use water. Any substance will do, including free space, which is why modern gravitational wave observatories are basically giant interferometers.